# Access Top of Personal Folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Accidentally dragged and dropped a day's worth of emails to somewhere bad.  I remember a word in one of the email's subject, and searched "All Mailboxes" and found it located in the "Top of Personal Folders".  How can I view this folder so I can access the other emails of that day?

Answer (score 0):

These items may be moved to the root folder of your mailbox. So, you cannot see the items in either the Folder List or the Outlook Today pane.

Please check this article:[Items placed in root folder seem to be lost in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2979451/items-placed-in-root-folder-seem-to-be-lost-in-outlook)

We can clear "Show home page by default for this folder" and then see if you can see these emails.